# JAVA- ¿Como recorro una lista numerica?

Tags: java

En strings para recorrer una lista es:

```
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(String x : lista){
                System.out.println(x);}
```

Para recorrer una lista numerica:

```
         List<Integer> promedio = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         for (int y : promedio){ //
                  System.out.println(y);}
```

Este post paso de ser una pregunta a un post informativo ya que pude resolverlo rapido.

El error en el post inicial estaba en no agregar ´{}´ en el for, lo cual hacia que no entrara en el mismo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar como inicializas la lista llamada promedio?

Comment: me tira "x cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Perdon, error de tipeo... me falto el {} en el for... dios mio.

Comment: Debes imprimir **y** no **x**. Ya que la variable **x** es la que utilizas para recorrer la lista tipo String.

Comment: no pasa nada, responde tu misma pregunta explicando lo que hiciste mal y ya

Comment: @Mr.ToxicMan recuerda siempre que es buena práctica usar { ... }, esto evitará errores en programación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debe funcionar definiendo el bucle `for` y evita el semicolon `;`. Como buena práctica te aconsejo usar siempre los brackets `{ ... }`.

**Recuerda también que para que entre al bucle, la lista debe tener elementos, de otra forma no realizará ninguna acción**:

```
 List<Integer> promedio = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         for (int y : promedio){ 
              System.out.println("valor: " + y);
         }
```

Si tu lista contiene elementos estos se mostrará sin problema, ejemplo:

```
 List<Integer> promedio = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 promedio.add(1);
 promedio.add(2);
 promedio.add(14);
 promedio.add(16);

         for (int y : promedio){ 
              System.out.println("valor: " + y);
         }
```

Comment: @Mr.ToxicMan tu lista también estaba vacía ?

Comment: nono, habia inputs para que los agregue el usuario. de paso te hago otra pregunta... no se pueden agregar valores a la lista de una cuando la definis no?? si o si hay que agregarlos con lista.add() no?

Comment: Exactamente, hay que agregar valores mediante el método add().

Answer (score 0):

Porque no es la variable x la que utilizas para definir cada item de la lista promedio, es y:

Cambia:

```
System.out.println(x);
```

Por:

```
System.out.println(y);
```